# SQL query classifying types of nodes in a binary tree

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-8.0, tree

I am using MySQL in trying to solve [a problem relating to a SQL query classifying types of nodes in a binary tree](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem?isFullScreen=true).

Specifically, the question states as follows:

> You are given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P, where N represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of N. Both columns have datatype as integer. Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:
>
> - Root: If node is root node.
> - Leaf: If node is leaf node.
> - Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
SELECT N,  
CASE  
    WHEN bst_outer.P IS NULL THEN "Root"  
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT bst_inner.N FROM BST bst_inner WHERE bst_inner.P = bst_outer.P) THEN "Leaf"  
    ELSE 'Inner'  
END   
FROM BST bst_outer;
```

The output after running the above query gives incorrect result, as there appears to be no nodes with `Leaf` classification. It seems like that the error lies on my second `WHEN` statement, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  bst_outer.N, 
        CASE WHEN bst_outer.P IS NULL THEN "Root" 
             WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  1
                    FROM  BST bst_inner
                    WHERE  bst_inner.P = bst_outer.N
                             ) THEN "Leaf"
             ELSE 'Inner' END
    FROM  BST bst_outer;
```

And, for efficiency, have something like

```
PRIMARY KEY(P, N),
INDEX(N, P)
```